# Unified Remote Control: Return shuffle value

Tags: lua, winamp

I'm using Unified Remote for a while now and i made a working shuffle button for Winamp since that's very useful.

Since that would be a binary value, i would like to be able to retrieve the shuffle_state in order to change the button's text.
Looking at [this page](http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?threadid=180297), i know that it's possible to give WM_USER messages of which id# 250 returns the shuffle state.

I'm just fiddling too long with the integration of this in lua, i can't get it to work.
Little help please? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide an [mcve]. We have no way to help if we don't know what is wrong.

Comment: PS: Constructing an MCVE takes time; and if you're doing a thorough job of it, then you will often solve your problem before you even finish composing the question. I lose many of my "favorite" questions this way, before I ever get to hit the "Ask" button.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I was under the assumption that someone with the UR system would respond. Then that person would have access to identical code that i have right here. But I'll shall paste the code here when i get home.